# Exploding path foldernames and storing it in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this filepath:

```
/www/htdocs/nether/http/helloworld/application/views/scripts/index/dashboard-stats.phtml
```

What I want to do is to store the helloworld folder in an array element. In this example the helloworld foldername is on the 5 place. But when placing this on a different webserver it could be on the second or thrid place. How to do this automatically?

I have a code which works,see below.

```
$pieces = explode($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], __FILE__);
$parts = explode("/", $pieces[1]);
echo $parts[1];
```

My question is, besides doing this automatically, is it possible to do this in less then 3 lines of code?

Comment: Is your question *How to do this automatically?* or *Is it possible to do this in less than 3 lines of code?* Also, are you trying to get the `helloworld` element each time or will it be something different? Please provide more specific criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.4.0 you could do the following:

```
echo explode("/",explode($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], __FILE__)[1])[1];
```

However I'd prefer your original version since it's much easier to read and you can check the resulting arrays to make sure they have at least 2 elements.